# Laravel with() slow

Tags: php, laravel, performance, eloquent

I'm having an issue where I only have about 5,000 rows I want to load with eager relations and the query is taking 5-10 seconds to complete. This application will quickly get up to 200k rows over the next month, so you can see why this is a big issue.

Here is my code:

```
$leads = Lead::with(['vertical', 'website', 'source', 'agent', 'assign', 'assign.buyer', 'returns'])->get();
$datatable = datatables()->of($leads);
dd($datatable );
```

It uses the Laravel Datatables plugin which simply adds limits for pagination to the query - https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

All of these relationships are properly set up in the model:

```
public function vertical()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Vertical');
}

public function website()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Website');
}

public function source()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Source');
}

public function agent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Agent');
}

public function assign()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Assign');
}

public function returns()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AssignReturn');
}
```

The `assign.buyer` relationship is also set up correctly within the `Assign` model.

Why would this be taking 5-10 seconds to load when I only have about 5,000 rows in the `Lead` table and its also being limited? Is this a Laravel-related issue, a Laravel Datatables issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I figured this out. Removing `->get()` actually allows the datatables package to perform pagination, rather than iterating through every single result.

This is what was causing the slowness.

Comment: To speed things up, you can also add db indexes on referenced db ids, if you have not done it already...